# Is it possible to use `guestEntries.beforeSave` to validate custom fields?

Tags: guest-entries, plugin-guestentries

Say, I want to validate an email address or a special URL e.g. YouTube URL, would I be able to use a custom plugin with the `guestEntries.beforeSave` hook to do this?

The basic hook call:

```
craft()->on( 'guestEntries.beforeSave', function(Event $event) {
    // Call custom validation here
});
```

Would I be able to setup a model with the method `defineAttributes` and run that?

Answer (score 1):

The only model passed into the `guestEntries.beforeSave` event and returns from it is Craft's [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/EntryModel), so even if you create your own `MyEntryModel` inside the event with it's own attributes and validation rules, there's not a clean way to return that model back to the controller to return to the template to display.

The easiest thing to do would be to fork the plugin and change [GuestEntriesController](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/blob/master/guestentries/controllers/GuestEntriesController.php#L175) so that's its using a custom `MyEntryModel` that extends Craft's `EntryModel` and adds it's additional attributes/validation rules as required.